# :methodの意味

Tags: perl

Perlのモジュールを読んでいたら以下の関数定義がありました。

```
sub connect :method { 

}
```

この、`:method`っていうのはどんな意味があるのか、ご存知の方がいたらご教示願いたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[サブルーチン属性](http://perldoc.jp/docs/perl/5.6.1/perlsub.pod)と言われるモノです。
一般にはユーザが適当につけて利用することができますが、
`:method`は[組み込みの属性](http://perldoc.jp/docs/perl/5.16.1/ext/attributes/attributes.pod)で、

> 参照された関数はメソッドであると 提示します

Comment: ご回答有難うございました。ドキュメント読んで理解出来ました。